# Issue of enumerating JSON Data using swift ForEach

Tags: json, swiftui

I am new to Swift and having issues writing a foreach for reading the JSON data below
I have defined the following structs and JSON data as shown below.

In my Content View I want to list each team name read from the json file.  In this case there is only one team.

The Json file is being loaded with no errors and i can see the data loaded.
this just seems to be an issue writing the correct ForEach.  I suspect it has to do with the data struct not having an int.  I have been working with adding Hashable protocol to the Data Struct.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**ContentView.swift**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private var people : [PersonElement] = PersonElement.allPeople
    private var data: [TeamSchema?] = TeamSchema.allTeams
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(data, id: \.?.data) {
                    team in Text("\(team.Name)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
            

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

**TeamSchema.swift**

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - TeamSchema
struct TeamSchema: Codable{
    let data: DataClass
    
    static let allTeams: [TeamSchema] = Bundle.main.decode(file: "TeamSchema.json")
    static let firstTeams: DataClass = allTeams[0].data
    
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable/*, Identifiable*/ {
    
//    static func == (lhs: DataClass, rhs: DataClass) -> Bool {
//    var results: Bool  = true
//        
//        
//        return results
//    }
    
    let team: Team
}

// MARK: - Team
struct Team: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name, number: String
    let league: League
    let division: Division
    let roster: [Roster]
    let typename: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, number, league, division, roster
        case typename = "__typename"
    }
}

// MARK: - Division
struct Division: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let type, typename: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, type
        case typename = "__typename"
    }
}

// MARK: - League
struct League: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let slug, typename: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, slug
        case typename = "__typename"
    }
}

// MARK: - Roster
struct Roster: Codable, Identifiable{
    let id: Int
    let memberNumber, displayName: String
    let matchesWon, matchesPlayed: Int
    let pa: Double
    let ppm, skillLevel: Int
    let typename: String
    let member: Member

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, memberNumber, displayName, matchesWon, matchesPlayed, pa, ppm, skillLevel
        case typename = "__typename"
        case member
    }
}

// MARK: - Member
struct Member: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let typename: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case typename = "__typename"
    }
}
```

**data.json. File**

```
[
    {
    "data": {
        "team": {
            "id": 12385690,
            "name": "Big League",
            "number": "87705",
            "league": {
                "id": 1342,
                "slug": "Easton",
                "__typename": "League"
            },
            "division": {
                "id": 374974,
                "type": "EIGHT",
                "__typename": "Division"
            },
            "roster": [
                {
                    "id": 87568674,
                    "memberNumber": "35293586",
                    "displayName": "yle randon",
                    "matchesWon": 0,
                    "matchesPlayed": 0,
                    "pa": 0,
                    "ppm": 0,
                    "skillLevel": 7,
                    "__typename": "EightBallPlayer",
                    "member": {
                        "id": 1288944,
                        "__typename": "Member"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 87568675,
                    "memberNumber": "35272278",
                    "displayName": "She Bilson",
                    "matchesWon": 1,
                    "matchesPlayed": 1,
                    "pa": 0.6666666666666666,
                    "ppm": 2,
                    "skillLevel": 6,
                    "__typename": "EightBallPlayer",
                    "member": {
                        "id": 2743566,
                        "__typename": "Member"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 87568678,
                    "memberNumber": "35212912",
                    "displayName": "Jan Pvene",
                    "matchesWon": 1,
                    "matchesPlayed": 1,
                    "pa": 0.6666666666666666,
                    "ppm": 2,
                    "skillLevel": 3,
                    "__typename": "EightBallPlayer",
                    "member": {
                        "id": 3159686,
                        "__typename": "Member"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 87568679,
                    "memberNumber": "35280608",
                    "displayName": "Tom Jevene",
                    "matchesWon": 1,
                    "matchesPlayed": 1,
                    "pa": 0.6666666666666666,
                    "ppm": 2,
                    "skillLevel": 6,
                    "__typename": "EightBallPlayer",
                    "member": {
                        "id": 3159692,
                        "__typename": "Member"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 87568676,
                    "memberNumber": "35280168",
                    "displayName": "Lan Gevans",
                    "matchesWon": 0,
                    "matchesPlayed": 1,
                    "pa": 0,
                    "ppm": 0,
                    "skillLevel": 3,
                    "__typename": "EightBallPlayer",
                    "member": {
                        "id": 3084400,
                        "__typename": "Member"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 87568681,
                    "memberNumber": "35217430",
                    "displayName": "Jou Launders",
                    "matchesWon": 1,
                    "matchesPlayed": 1,
                    "pa": 0.6666666666666666,
                    "ppm": 2,
                    "skillLevel": 3,
                    "__typename": "EightBallPlayer",
                    "member": {
                        "id": 2880864,
                        "__typename": "Member"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 87568680,
                    "memberNumber": "35240106",
                    "displayName": "Barry Allen",
                    "matchesWon": 0,
                    "matchesPlayed": 0,
                    "pa": 0,
                    "ppm": 0,
                    "skillLevel": 3,
                    "__typename": "EightBallPlayer",
                    "member": {
                        "id": 3238664,
                        "__typename": "Member"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 87568677,
                    "memberNumber": "35280228",
                    "displayName": "Siane Shake",
                    "matchesWon": 0,
                    "matchesPlayed": 0,
                    "pa": 0,
                    "ppm": 0,
                    "skillLevel": 2,
                    "__typename": "EightBallPlayer",
                    "member": {
                        "id": 3137951,
                        "__typename": "Member"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "__typename": "Team"
        }
    }
}
]
```

Comment: You have declared allTeams to be of type [TeamSchema] so don’t declare the property in your view differently. If you fix that writing the ForEach should be much easier

Comment: I am still working on the ForEach Statement.  I am trying different things.  I am following an example on YouTube ---By Indently.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J06P6AMKo5Q.      I think in general this is a good model to follow.  What seems to complicate my case is the json I pull from an API is not hashable.

Comment: you could try something like this: 
`private var data: [TeamSchema] = TeamSchema.allTeams` and 
              `ForEach(data, id: \.self) { schema in  Text("\(schema.data.team.name)") }`.
              Or better still make TeamSchema Identifiable.

Comment: Thanks I am working on your suggestion. I am getting TeamSchema needs to conform to Hashable.  Will followup.